# Django VSCode: How to make django-html format as expectedl?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, visual-studio-code

I've seen a ton of unanswered questions about VSCode formatting (and if not here, where do you ask these questions?).

There are 2 main issues I run into constantly when I'm trying to write django-html templates.

## 1. Basic HTML tag linebreak doesn't occur in django-html files.

When you write an html tag, and press enter inside of it, it should split the tag with an empty line in the middle like.

**Expected behavior** (pipe "|" represents the cursor):

```
<!-- Write the tag -->
<div>|</div>

<!-- Press enter -->
<tag>
  |
</tag>
```

Here's what's happening in the django-html file after enter:

```
<!-- Press enter -->
<tag>
|</tag>
```

How do you fix this WITH proper template tag formatting (below)?

## 2. Django template tags don't indent as expected.

Tags within if, with, block, etc. tags should be indented. (treated like html)
**Expected result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if x %}
      <p>I did x</p>
    {% else %} 
      <p> I did else</p>
    {% endif %}
    <nav class="navbar">
    </nav> 
    {% block content %}
      <div class="content">
        <p>I'm in contente</p>
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead, the html tags within the django template tags are flattened on the same indent level.
**Actual result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if x %}
    <p>I did x</p>
    {% else %} 
    <p> I did else</p>
    {% endif %}
    <nav class="navbar">
    </nav> 
    {% block content %}
    <div class="content">
      <p>I'm in contente</p>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Also if you're extending a template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block main %}
  <div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What happens:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}
<div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

## Conclusion

I've used both beautify and prettier to try to solve the problems, but neither did the expected behavior 100% (especially with the template tags), but they did help.

I believe with slight tweaks they could have the expected behavior and treat django template tags as html tags AND have the html linebreak feature.

How do you get these to format with these 2 simple specifications correctly?

Comment: it is `jinja2` not `django-html`, so search on how to beautify a jinja2 code.

Comment: @Moha369 Ooooo, that's helpful! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result by using the [Twig Language 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2) extension and putting the following in my project settings:

```json
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "twig"
  },
```